# Splitting an address

Tags: c#

i have a small proplem and its i need to split Address like '127.0.0.1:7777' with the symbol ':' to two variables first one leads to the ip and second one leads to the port example on php `list($IP, $Port) = explode(':', '127.0.0.1:7777');`

Comment: Use `.Split()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @UnholySheep Worth noting is that that can break badly for IPv6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract IP Address and port for both IPv4 and IPv6 you can use the below code:

```
Uri url;
string ipv4 = "127.0.0.1:7777";
if (Uri.TryCreate(String.Format("http://{0}", ipv4), UriKind.Absolute, out url))
{
    string ip = url.Host;
    int port = url.Port;
    Console.WriteLine($"IP: {ip} Port: {port}");
}
```

Testing the same with an IPv6 address:

```
string ipv6 = "[2001:db8:1f70::999:de8:7648:6e8]:100";
```

Output:

> IP: 127.0.0.1 Port: 7777
>
> IP: 2001:db8:1f70:0:999:de8:7648:6e8 Port: 100

.net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QWAt4N

Comment: thanks for your help but thatsn't what i meant, i need it as a variables the ip as string and the port as integer so iam currently trying with that .Split(...)

Comment: @JohnMagdy you can parse url.Port into an integer to get port as an integer. IP address is already available as a variable using url.Host.

Comment: thanks i had used some of your words and some of Nikita 's words to undertsand how to fix my proplem and script what i need thanks so much guys

Edit: GrantWinney i migght try it on next time thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Split you can do it this way to make it work with IPv6 as well.

```
string ip = "127.0.0.1:8080";
int lastIndexOfColon = ip.LastIndexOf(':');
string host = ip.Substring(0, lastIndexOfColon);
string port = ip.Substring(lastIndexOfColon + 1);
```